# javac version is 1.8, but getting warning "major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler."

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

The warning then proceeds to say "It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded."

Running `java -version` and `javac -version` both return java 1.8.

Any idea why I am getting the error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT: I may have found the culprit(shown in picture below), but I don't know how to change it to java 8.

[image]

Comment: You can't use Java 8 with Android - it doesn't support it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As i know you cant have java 8 right now for android. as Mr @Jon Skeet said